# PHPUnit on Wamp

Tags: phpunit, wampserver

Is there a tutorial for PHP unit on windows?  I followed a couple of tutorials and got PHPUnit installed, but when I run it, all it does is output the the test's contents (IE the php file itself).  Is there a better way to do this?  I'm just going through the command line right now, but am open to using netbeans or some other environment.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has great PHPUnit support. In properties of PHP project you just need to select test folder and IDE gets it done for you - including building nice reports.
Apart from Netbeans, you should probably run test from command line (PHP CLI), not your browser.